# generate candle point for empty date

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to create an empty point for the dates which are not included in the data?

Tried to use `pointInterval: 24*3600*1000,` but doesn't have any result.

In this example we have a gap between 31th July and 7th August which I would like to fill with empty points.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick/

Comment: He wants to know how to create an empty data point (0) when the date doesn't include any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `ordinal: false` as an option on the `xAxis`. Like this:

```
xAxis: {
  ordinal: false
}
```

**API on xAxis.ordinal:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

> In an ordinal axis, the points are equally spaced in the chart regardless of the actual time or x distance between them. This means that missing data for nights or weekends will not take up space in the chart.
>
> Defaults to true.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/phLz68r9/